# is it possible to find PPP monthly data?

Tags: macroeconomics

For most of the databases, monthly PPP data is not provided. How it can be possible to find monthly PPP data?  i mean PPP(exchange rate) conversion factors.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't exist. Gdp is quarterly.

There are no short term indicators like that on a global levels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a monthly PPP series but you might want to contact the OECD as they have a monthly comparative price levels(https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/economics/data/prices/comparative-price-levels_data-00536-en)

https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=CPL

which uses ratios of PPPs for private final consumption expenditure to exchange rates. The monthly PPPs used to derive the table are OECD estimates.   I don't think they would give it out to the public as this may be an internal series they use (which may have quality issues) but its worth contacting them about it.